# Subnet of the AWS VPC physically isolated?

Tags: amazon-web-services, subnet, vpc

For Subnets in the same VPC, is Region independent?

I would like to set up more than two fully independent Availability Zones for Elastic Load Balancer(ELB).

Is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

Yes:

- Within a Region you create a VPC
- The VPC is a logical concept and spans AZs
- You then create subnets within the VPC for each AZ
- Each AZ is a physically separate datacentre from another, normally 3 AZs or more per region
- When you set up an ELB, you select the subnets that you want to use, select a subnet in each AZ
- ELB will add instances across all 3 (or more) subnets/AZs